# If a class is inherited by two other classes will those child classes have the fields of the base class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, datatable

I have three classes; one base class and two child class.

```
public class Employee
{
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
public class ContractEmployee : Employee
{
    [Column(Order = 6)]
    public int HoursWorked { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 7)]
    public int HourlyPay { get; set; }
}
public class PermanentEmployee : Employee
{
    [Column(Order = 5)]
    public int AnnualSalary { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if I create a function which uses `DataTable`.

```
private DataTable ConvertEmployeesForDisplay(List<Employee> employees)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID");
    dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
    dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
    dt.Columns.Add("Gender");
    dt.Columns.Add("AnuualSalary");
    dt.Columns.Add("HourlyPay");
    dt.Columns.Add("HoursWorked");
    dt.Columns.Add("Type");

    foreach (Employee **employee** in employees)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ID"] = employee.ID;
        dr["FirstName"] = employee.FirstName;
        dr["LastName"] = employee.LastName;
        dr["Gender"] = employee.Gender;

        if (employee is PermanentEmployee)
        {
            dr["AnuualSalary"] = ((PermanentEmployee)employee).AnnualSalary;
            dr["Type"] = "Permanent";
        }
        else
        {
            dr["HourlyPay"] = ((ContractEmployee)employee).HourlyPay;
            dr["HoursWorked"] = ((ContractEmployee)employee).HoursWorked;
            dr["Type"] = "Contract";
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

My doubts
1. Here how the employee object is getting PermanentEmployee when it is not present in Employee Class?
2. Is it because the employee class is getting all fields of child classes?

P.S: If I am unclear ( cannot post an EF image here require reputation points) please refer to [this post](http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2014/06/part-19-table-per-hierarchy-tph_5.html).

Comment: How can "PermanentEmployee" "be present" in "Employee" class? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: _If a class in inherited by two another classes will the base class have the fields of child class?_ it does not have the properties. but i think data stored there until you cast it. then its usable.

Comment: @Euphoric - It makes sense to me.

Comment: @Enigmativity Then explain. Because this question has zero sense.

Comment: @Euphoric - I think the OP has the mistaken mindset that casting from one type to another **changes** the object - so when going from `PermanentEmployee` to `Employee` it **trims** the extra fields, thus when going from `Employee` back to `PermanentEmployee` it must gain extra fields, but those have been lost so where do they come from. We know that the object doesn't actually change when casting, but I think that's what the OP is trying to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

The classes you have defined allow you to create objects of any of those three types.

This means you could create the types that **look like** the following:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

public class ContractEmployee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int HoursWorked { get; set; }
    public int HourlyPay { get; set; }
}

public class PermanentEmployee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int AnnualSalary { get; set; }
}
```

So that means, when you create any of those three, they are always the type that has been created and that they always have those properties (and underlying fields) allocated. They are never a different type and they never have different data.

But because `ContractEmployee` & `PermanentEmployee` both inherit from `Employee` they can both **appear** to be of type `Employee` when they are cast as `Employee`.

Now you could start with an instance of `ContractEmployee`, cast it as `Employee` and it will look like an `Employee`, but it will still be `ContractEmployee`. If you tried to cast it to back to `ContractEmployee` it would work, but if you tried to cast as `PermanentEmployee` it would fail.

So, yes, a child class will have all of the properties/fields of the parent class. Child classes can have extra properties/fields than the parent class. Parent classes never get the properties/fields of the child classes.

Just remember that when a class is created it gets all of its properties/fields and they never change. The class can be cast to a parent type and it then only **appears** to have the parent type properties/fields.

Now, having said all of this, this only applies for `public` and `protected` properties/fields. If the fields are `private` or `internal` then you don't get that behaviour. `private` properties/fields are only visible within the definition of the class and `internal` properties/fields are only visible within the assembly in which the class is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're creating the list something like:

```
var list = new List<Employee>() {
    new ContractEmployee() { ... },
    new PermanentEmployee() { ... },
};
```

that'll work because of the explicit conversions to derived types in `ConvertEmployeesForDisplay`, which allows access to the properties on the derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

In your `employee` collection you have both list of types `ContractEmployee` and `PermanentEmployeee` which is derived from `Employee` class.
This will work due to explicit conversions.

If the `Employee` class is of type `ContractEmployee` then it will contain the fields/properties

```
HoursWorked
HourlyPay
```

If the `Employee` class is of type `PermanentEmployee` then it will contain the field/property

```
AnuualSalary
```

Which will resolve at run-time.

Comment: The line "Which will resolve at run-time" is not particularly clear. I understand what you're saying but if someone is trying to learn about inheritance this sounds like magic. Maybe you need to give an example of what you mean?

Answer (score -2):

1 - In this code Polymorphic behavior of employee is used.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx

The object employee can be any of both types either PermanentEmployee or ContractEmployee.

2. No this is not the case. Base class doesn't contain data members of child class